# Arrange divs in a circle and animate radius outwards

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** I want to arrange divs in a circle and animate the radius. Unfortunately, I seem to have some sort of binding issue with my variables. Trying to figure this out since 3 days. What can I do to get out of this predicament? I mean how do I solve this in an "elegant fashion"?

**What I Tried:** I did a few console logs and everything implies that javascript has problems interpreting what I mean with "this".

I also found out that I need to bind the parameter inside requestAnimationFrame but I cant imagine binding every variable and function name so I must be doing something wrong here.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh23pzvb/4/

**Code:**

```
function explodeRocket(obj) {
  this.elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  this.particle = [];
  this.radius = obj.radius;
  this.color = ['red', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'orchid']
    this.interval = 2 * Math.PI / obj.particles;

  this.init = function() {
    this.create();
    this.blast();
  }

  this.init();

  this.create = function() {
    for(var i = 0;  i < obj.particles; i++) {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      this.elem[i].style.background = this.color[obj.colorIndex];
      this.particle.push(new this.Properties(0, obj.x, obj.y));
      this.updatePosition(i);
    } 
  }

  this.Properties = function(angle, x, y) {
    this.angle = angle;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

    this.updatePosition = function(index) {
    this.elem[index].style.left = this.particle[index].x + 'px';
    this.elem[index].style.top = this.particle[index].y + 'px';
  }

  this.blast = function() {
    for(var i = 0;  i < 10 - 1; i++) {
      if(this.radius < obj.radiusMax) {
        this.radius += 0.2;
      }
      this.particle[i].x = Math.round(window.innerWidth) / 2 + obj.radius * Math.cos(this.particle[i].angle) ;
      this.particle[i].y = Math.round(window.innerHeight) / 2 + obj.radius * Math.sin(this.particle[i].angle);
      this.updatePosition(i);
      this.particle[i].angle += this.interval;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(this.blast);
  }
}


new explodeRocket({ 
    particles: 4, colorIndex: 0, radius: 0, radiusMax: 200, x: 0, y: 0 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bug 1:**

You call the `init()` before the `create()` function initialised, so you cannot call it. You can fix it by putting the `init()` at the end of the `explodeRocket` function, so all your functions exist when calling `init()`.

**Bug 2:**

`.blast()` runs the loop too many times. You only have 4 particles, but the loop runs 9 times. You can fix it by running the loop only `particle.length` times:

```
for(var i = 0;  i < this.particle.length; i++) {
```

**Bug 3:**

The `this` bug. Your code loses `this`, when you call `requestAnimationFrame`. You can use the `Function.call`, which takes the `this` object as the first parameter. It's common to bind `this` to some other variable (like `self`) to overcome these issues:

```
var self = this;
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    self.blast.call(self);
});
```

**Bug 4:**

You're referring to `obj.radius`, which is always 0. You should use `this.radius`:

```
this.particle[i].x = Math.round(window.innerWidth) / 2 + this.radius * Math.cos(this.particle[i].angle);
this.particle[i].y = Math.round(window.innerHeight) / 2 + this.radius * Math.sin(this.particle[i].angle);
```

**Bug 5:**

You probably don't want to rotate full 1/4th of round always, so animate 1/40th of circle per frame:

```
this.particle[i].angle += this.interval * 0.1;
```

**Bug 6:**

You probably want the particles to be evenly spaced, so intialize the particle with proper radius:

```
this.particle.push(new this.Properties(this.interval * i, obj.x, obj.y));
```

**Complete code:**

```
function explodeRocket(obj) {
  var self = this;
  this.elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  this.particle = [];
  this.radius = obj.radius;
  this.color = ['red', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'orchid']
    this.interval = 2 * Math.PI / obj.particles;

  this.init = function() {
    this.create();
    this.blast();
  }

  this.create = function() {
    for(var i = 0;  i < obj.particles; i++) {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      this.elem[i].style.background = this.color[obj.colorIndex];
      this.particle.push(new this.Properties(this.interval * i, obj.x, obj.y));
      this.updatePosition(i);
    } 
  }

  this.Properties = function(angle, x, y) {
    this.angle = angle;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

    this.updatePosition = function(index) {
    this.elem[index].style.left = this.particle[index].x + 'px';
    this.elem[index].style.top = this.particle[index].y + 'px';
  }

  this.blast = function() {
    for(var i = 0;  i < this.particle.length; i++) {
      if(this.radius < obj.radiusMax) {
        this.radius += 0.2;
      }
      this.particle[i].x = Math.round(window.innerWidth) / 2 + this.radius * Math.cos(this.particle[i].angle);
      this.particle[i].y = Math.round(window.innerHeight) / 2 + this.radius * Math.sin(this.particle[i].angle);
      this.updatePosition(i);
      this.particle[i].angle += this.interval * 0.1;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        self.blast.call(self);
    });
  }

  this.init();
}


new explodeRocket({ 
    particles: 4, colorIndex: 0, radius: 0, radiusMax: 200, x: 0, y: 0 
})
```

That should do it!

**Edit:**

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3nt2kd0/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try moving your `this.init();` at the end of the constructor.

After doing that there are some other errors thrown, inside your `blast()` method, which probably has something to do with the fact that the `this.particles` array only has 4 elements and you are trying to do 10 iterations or so.

As a tip, you could move most, if not all, of the methods on the `explodeRocket.prototype` so that instances share the same method instance, like so:

```
function ExplodeRocket(obj) {
    //yada yada
}

ExplodeRocket.prototype.blast = function blast() {
    //yada yada
}
```

Comment: I did vote for jehna but I will give you a point since your tip is great. Eventhough I used the prototype before, I thought it wasnt neccesary for this particular work. Mistake of my part.

Comment: It's not a mistake; if you plan to only have one instance of this, you don't really need to move the methods to the `prototype`. Cheers